# How to update a hardware watchdog from boot?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, petalinux

I have set up a Linux system using Yocto on a Zynq-7000 with Petalinux 2021.1. My current task involves resetting a hardware watchdog every 2 seconds. Resetting the watchdog once my system is already up and running is not an issue. However, I am facing a challenge in resetting the watchdog during the boot process.

My understanding is that the u-boot phase takes less than 2 seconds, so resetting the watchdog at that moment is unnecessary. However, there is a significant gap of approximately 40 seconds between the kernel launch and the user connection.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

I tried to launch a service at beginning of Kernel but without success.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Boune.

Comment: Your title ("*How launch a program between u-boot and kernel?*") doesn't match the rest of your post, and seems like an [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I update the title, thank's you !

Comment: I think it's a poor hardware design if the watchdog runs without having to be enabled first.

Comment: You can't say that without know the application.

Comment: A 2 second interval for a WDT may be reasonable once a system is fully operational, but during boot could be problematic. A WDT tickle/kick would be advisable in U-Boot. Build your U-Boot with WDT support. Linux kernel could be trickier, since once the MMU is enabled you'll need a virtual address to tickle the WDT. That's a task performed during the initialization of a driver. But not sure if you can wait that long.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a kernel module.
Check if one of these modules is something that you are looking for:
https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842055/Cadence+WDT+Driver 
https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841776/Axi+Watchdog

If not, you can write a small kernel module and put it into the `initrd`/`initramfs` so it will be loaded on start.

https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2021.2-English/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide/Creating-and-Adding-Custom-Kernel-Modules

`initramfs` also supports running some shell scripts on the start but I'm not sure how it works on Petalinux.

If the time is still too late you could build the kernel with the module included (as built-in). There is a mechanism named `initcall` which controls the order of the built-in modules' initialization.
https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Concepts/linux-cpu-3.html

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I don't know if I say right, but I can't put my driver before some important steps of boot. When I put arch_initcall my driver is load at 16 seconds. So it's too late for my watchdog.

Comment: @Boune The earliest initcall is `early_initcall`, I'm not sure if the module should be called in that stage but worth a try. If that still isn't enough, then only solution I could think of is to run some program from u-boot before loading the kernel.

Comment: I will try this ! I'm not sure but I think I can't run a program in the background between u-boot and kernel, juste once a sequential program.

Comment: "*only solution I could think of is to run some program from u-boot before loading the kernel*" - FYI U-Boot has built-in support for WDT. Why concoct such an elaborate/complicated scheme when a simple WDT tickle/kick in U-Boot just before the jump to the kernel accomplishes almost the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I have a ZYNQ(7020) board with hardware watchdog too. My board's HW watchdog feed time is 125ms control with gpio, my solution is:

1. add gpio watchdog in kernel
   kernel support gpio watchdog , when image jump from uboot to kernel ,kernel will feed hw watch dog, just open gpio watchdog, kernel will feed hw watchdog always.
   add gpio watch dog to your defconfig ,locate in Device Drivers → Watchdog Timer Support →  Watchdog device controlled through GPIO-line
2. add gpio watchdog to dts
   add gpio watchdog to amba node
   &amba {

   ```
    watchdog {      

    compatible = "linux,wdt-gpio";

    gpios = <&gpio0 44 0>;

    hw_algo = "toggle";

    hw_margin_ms = <200>;

    always-running;
   ```

   };
   };

   3. check watchdog
      After kernel start you will found hw watchdog in /sys/class/watchdog/

> ## ls -alh /sys/class/watchdog/ total 0 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Jul 26 07:27 . drwxr-xr-x   34 root     root           0 Jul 26
>
> 06:45 .. lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Jul 26 07:27
> watchdog0 -> ../../devices/soc0/amba/amba:watchdog/watchdog/watchdog0
> lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Jul 26 07:27 watchdog1 ->
> ../../devices/soc0/amba/f8005000.watchdog/watchdog/watchdog1

watchdog0: hw watchdog
watchdog1: software watchdog for app

Comment: Do you know how delete this system once the system is boot ?